# Android utilize V8 without WebView

Tags: javascript, android, v8

I'm exercising executing javascript from Java.  Rhino works very well for this on desktop, but has to fall back to (slow) interpreted mode on Android (due to dalvik being unable to execute the Java bytecode the Rhino JIT compiles).

Android has its built-in V8 javascript engine which is accessed internally via JNI and ought to give much better performance than Rhino; however, the only way I can find to access it is indirectly through a WebView.

Unfortunately, WebView requires a Context, and crashes with NPE with a null context, so I'm unable to even instantiate a dummy WebView to merely execute the code and return the result.  The nature of my exercise doesn't really allow me to provide a Context for WebView, so I'm hoping perhaps there's something I'm overlooking.

Several of these V8Threads run in parallel, so it's not really feasible (as far as I'm aware) to add a WebView to my layout and hide it, as I don't believe a single WebView can execute functions in multiple threads.

```
private class V8Thread extends Thread
{
    private WebView webView;
    private String source;

    private double pi;
    private int i, j;

    public V8Thread(int i, int j)
    {
        pi = 0.0;
        this.i = i;
        this.j = j;

        source = "";

        try {
            InputStreamReader isReader = new InputStreamReader(assetManager.open("pi.js"));
            int blah = isReader.read();
            while (blah != -1)
            {
                source += (char)blah;
                blah = isReader.read();
            }

            webView = new WebView(null);
            webView.loadData(source, "text/html", "utf-8");
            webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            webView.addJavascriptInterface(this, "V8Thread");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public double getResult()
    {
        return pi;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() 
    {
        webView.loadUrl("javascript:Androidpicalc("+i+","+j+")");
    }
}
```

Ideally there must be some supported way to call V8 directly, or at least execute javascript without requiring an actual WebView, as it seems a rather clunky and convoluted method just to run javascript code.

**UPDATE**

I've rearranged my code a bit, though unseen here is that now I am instantiating the V8Threads on the AsyncTasks's onPreExecute() while keeping everything else in doInBackground().  The source code is read in earlier in the program, so it's not redundantly re-read for each thread.

Because now the V8Thread is instantiated on the UI Thread, I can pass it the current view's Context (I'm using fragments so I can't just pass it "this"), so it no longer crashes.

```
private class V8Thread extends Thread
{
    private WebView webView;

    private double pi;
    private int i, j;

    public V8Thread(int i, int j)
    {
        pi = 0.0;
        this.i = i;
        this.j = j;

        source = "";

        webView = new WebView(v.getContext());
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    public void setResult(String in)
    {
        Log.d("Pi",in);
    }

    public double getResult()
    {
        return pi;
    }

    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.addJavascriptInterface(this, "V8Thread");
        webView.loadData(source, "text/html", "utf-8");
        //webView.loadUrl("javascript:Androidpicalc("+i+","+j+")");
        webView.loadUrl("javascript:test()");
        Log.d("V8Thread","Here");
    }
}
```

However, when executing, logcat spits out one per thread of the error "Can't get the viewWidth after the first layout" and the javascript code never executes.  I know the thread fires completely, because the "Here" log message is sent.  Here's the relevant test() function in the js code.

```
function test()
{
V8Thread.setResult("blah");
}
```

Working correctly, "blah" should show up four times in logcat, but it never shows up.  Could be my source code is read incorrectly, but I doubt that.

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(assetManager.open("pi.js"));
while (scan.hasNextLine()) source += scan.nextLine();
```

The only other thing I can imagine is that due to these aforementioned errors, the webView never actually gets around to executing the javascript.

I'll also add that pi.js contains only javascript, no HTML whatsoever.  However, even when I wrap it in just enough HTML for it to qualify as a webpage, still no luck.

Comment: It may be a little late, but have you tried disabling optimization for Rhino? See this Q/A: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3859305/problems-using-rhino-on-android#comment4103792_3859485

Comment: Interesting read on various engines that could be used - https://medium.com/tech-quizlet/comparison-shopping-searching-for-javascript-engines-for-android-bdc656538f2e

Answer (score 10):

You can create a new V8 Context via its API and use that to execute your JavaScript, look into https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/v8 `include` directory which contains two C++ header files. Link against the libwebcore.so (compiled from https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/webkit) library via the NDK, nothing special.

```
v8::Persistent<v8::Context> context = v8::Persistent<v8::Context>::New(v8::Context::New());
context->Enter();
```

Refer to https://developers.google.com/v8/get_started which will work on Android. Just make sure the device actually ships with V8 (some older devices ship with JSC [JavaScript Core]).

Comment: Are you suggesting we compile V8 and include it in the app? I've seen no documentation anywhere on the internet for how to link against, and use, the device's V8 installation. You say it's nothing special, but I don't know where to start... :/

Comment: V8 is already available inside libwebcore.so, just use it from your NDK code.

Comment: Has anybody tried this yet? Sounds almost too good to be true.

Comment: Do you know (how to find out) which version of V8 is available that way? And if an old version, can one just embed their own copy of the latest one?

Comment: When I attempt to load the library, via: 
`static{
        System.loadLibrary("webcore");
    }`
I get an UnsatisfiedLinkError
Has anyone successfully loaded the lib via what is done here: [WebViewCore](https://www.gitorious.org/rf4ceandroid/frameworks_base/source/690b964c5dc29608b336b2464ba123bcef9d9edf:core/java/android/webkit/WebViewCore.java "WebViewCore")

Comment: This really cries out for a working Github example app that does this. Is it possible to use the v8 javascript engine by including only a tiny stub code instead of the rather-large full v8 binary?

Comment: @RoundSparrowhilltx you do need to link against libwebcore.so, the "rather-large full v8 binary" is already on the device.

Comment: Am i right that on android 4.4+ **there is no webkit**? So it's imposibble to load `libwebcore.so`

Comment: According to [Android 7.0 Behavior Changes](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/nougat/android-7.0-changes.html#ndk) ,I think this solution will not work as expected.

Answer (score 6):

A bit of a late response but it may be useful to anyone stumbling upon this question. I used the [J2V8](https://github.com/eclipsesource/j2v8) library which is a Java wrapper on Google's V8 engine. This library comes with pre-compiled V8 binaries for x86 and armv7l Android devices. It work seamlessly. See [here](http://eclipsesource.com/blogs/getting-started-with-j2v8/) for tutorials. Just keep in mid that since pure V8 is just an Ecmascript engine, there is no DOM element available.

Answer (score 2):

I found this really nifty open source ECMAScript compliant JS Engine completely written in C called [duktape](http://duktape.org/)

> Duktape is an embeddable Javascript engine, with a focus on portability and compact footprint.

You'd still have to go through the ndk-jni business, but it's pretty straight forward. Just include the `duktape.c` and `duktape.h` from the distributable source [here](http://duktape.org/download.html)(If you don't want to go through the build process yourself) into the jni folder, update the Android.mk and all that stuff.

Here's a sample C snippet to get you started.

```
#include "duktape.h"

JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL
Java_com_ndktest_MainActivity_evalJS
(JNIEnv * env, jobject obj, jstring input){
    duk_context *ctx = duk_create_heap_default();
    const char *nativeString = (*env)->GetStringUTFChars(env, input, 0);
    duk_push_string(ctx, nativeString);
    duk_eval(ctx);
    (*env)->ReleaseStringUTFChars(env, input, nativeString);
    jstring result = (*env)->NewStringUTF(env, duk_to_string(ctx, -1));
    duk_destroy_heap(ctx);
    return result;
}
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Can you get a hold of the `Context` that is your `Application`?  There are a couple ways to do this.

1. Call [getApplication()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#getApplication%28%29) from your `Activity` (`Application` is a child of `Context`)
2. Call [getApplicationContent()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getApplicationContext%28%29) from a `Context` (`Context` likely being your `Activity`)

**UPDATE**

According to this [Android documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html#BindingJavaScript), your bound Javascript code will run in a separate process anyways, so there should be no need to set it up in its own `Thread`.

From the link:

> Note: The object that is bound to your JavaScript runs in another thread and not in the thread in which it was constructed.  (The 'object' being referred to is the JavascriptInterface class)

Comment: If I try to give WebView my actual Context, it crashes with "Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()"

This seems to be related to trying to access elements that are on the UI Thread from another thread.

Comment: Ah, I wasn't paying attention that this is in another thread.  I will look at it a bit more and update my answer if I have any suggestions.

Comment: Additionally, I should add that these are being called from an AsyncTask, so that further complicates things.

Comment: I'll need to take that into consideration when refining the code.  However after giving it some intense thought I've come across an idea that has improved the situation, but presented only another problem.  I will update my question shortly.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [AndroidJSCore project](https://github.com/ericwlange/AndroidJSCore).  It is not based on V8, but JavaScriptCore.  The current version (2.2+) supports JIT compilation on all processors not named MIPS.

**UPDATE 2018:** AndroidJSCore has been superseded by [LiquidCore](https://github.com/LiquidPlayer/LiquidCore), which is, in fact, based on V8.  Not only does it include the V8 engine, but all of Node.js is available as well.