# android string equation to java code

Tags: java, android

How could I parse a string statement into code?

e.g.:

```
    boolean isOnline = true;
    boolean isConnected = true;
    String statement = "isOnline && isConnected";

    if(statement) // do something
```

Comment: It's really not clear what you're asking here.  Are you asking how to evaluate a SQLite expression in Java?

Comment: no just asking how would you translate a string equation to java code 

like i wrote up there.

Comment: @anonimoo90 you want to evaluate the *statement* that you stored in your String?

Comment: there's nothing built in to Java to do that.  You're looking for a parser, which is not a trivial project.

Comment: @LukasKnuth yes thats what i want

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
   boolean isOnline = true;
   boolean isConnected = true;
   String statement = "isOnline && isConnected";
   String[] split = statement .split(" && ");

   if(split.lenght > split[0].equals("isOnline") && split[1].equals("isConnected")){
       // do something
   }
```

Comment: And how would this handle variable names and expressions, like in the question?

Comment: sorry this doesnt work for me, like i said i will type variable names in string format and need the string to run as an statement like in the example i gave

Comment: @anonimoo90 how about now?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest the following strategy depending your knowledge on how is structured your string expression.

**1- Develop your own parser.**

You will have to develop your own grammar.
There is an ANTLR port on android : [ANTLR and Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7596609/antlr-and-android)

> Ie, you will get with your expression ("isOnline" && "isConnected")

**2- Use reflexivity/introspection**

Once the string is parsed, you could use reflexivity to translate field or method expression into a field or a method.

> Ie, you will translate "isOnline" to isOnline and "isConnected" to
>   isConnected

Good luck for this

Answer (score 0):

The original Java has a built-in [JavaCompiler class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/tools/JavaCompiler.html) which would allow you to compile and load code that forms a complete valid .java file.

Android does not have this.

You could try to use some JavaScript engine written in Java (see, e.g., [Android utilize V8 without WebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6880778/android-utilize-v8-without-webview)).

However, this would still not allow you to access local variables declared in your Java function.
(With the [reflection API](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/reflect/package-summary.html), you would be able to read the values of class fields.)