# Download data from webview when the app is closed

Tags: android, android-studio, webview

Hi I'm writing an android app which has to retrieve some infos from a website using webview and js, I figured out how to do that when app is opened, is there a way to get these infos when app is closed? Almost like whatsapp and gmail do...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not going to be able to use a WebView when the app isn't showing. What you can do is use a service, which runs in the background, there you can make requests to download data over the Internet.

More info
http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html

Keep in mind that your standard service will run on your applications main thread, so you may need to provide threading for yourself.

To make your code trigger at a given time checkout alarms:
http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidTaskScheduling/article.html

For non WebView web browsing consider:
[Use V8 JavaScript engine to execute JS lib without webview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19408245/use-v8-javascript-engine-to-execute-js-lib-without-webview)

Comment: Ohh... Because what my app does... Is opening a website, log in, click on one element and take what there is on the page... Is there a way ti do that without a webview?

Comment: I suppose you could make use of some of the things mentioned here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19408245/use-v8-javascript-engine-to-execute-js-lib-without-webview but it will be a lot of work and error prone as you will have to navigate a website and websites are prone to changing how they work "under the hood"

Comment: Remember to up vote and accept answer if it helped you

Answer (score 0):

You will need to run your logic on a service.
The service will run on the background and do your app logic.
If you app is doing CPU intensive operations, run your service on another thread. Read the official documentation of [services](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html) for more information on how to use them.