# Access JavaScript Engine:V8 directly from android application

Tags: javascript, android, v8

I need to access V8 from my Android Application dierctly. I dont want to use Rhino or J2V8 and I dont want to create a WebView. What is the best way to do that? Is there an API for V8?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use V8 JavaScript engine to execute JS lib without webview](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19408245/use-v8-javascript-engine-to-execute-js-lib-without-webview)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can embed V8 directly in your App, although it will add to your binary size significantly. There is a C++ API for V8 which embedders like Chromium and Node.js use. See the [V8 Embedder's Guide](https://github.com/v8/v8/wiki/Embedder's%20Guide) to get started.