# android Rhino error can't load this type of class file

Tags: android, android-webview, rhino

I'm using Rhino in android to execute JavaScript function code in Android(java) and get the result from this code, but I got this exception

> 01-22 11:33:57.063: E/AndroidRuntime(29175): Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: can't load this type of class file

This is my code

```
String test = "function abc(x,y) {return x+y;}";
    org.mozilla.javascript.Context context = org.mozilla.javascript.Context.enter();
    try {
        ScriptableObject scope = context.initStandardObjects();
        Scriptable that = context.newObject(scope);
        Function fct = context.compileFunction(scope, test, "script", 1, null);
        Object result = fct.call(context, scope, that, new Object[] { 2, 3 });
        Log.i("JML...Info", "jajajajaj = " + org.mozilla.javascript.Context.jsToJava(result, int.class));
    } finally {
        org.mozilla.javascript.Context.exit();
    }
```

I got the exception on method

> Function fct = context.compileFunction(scope, test, "script", 1, null);

I wrote this code in method onCreate() after load the webview and I use rhino1_7R2.jar as a jar for Rhino.

Please help me and if u know any other way to get a value from JavaScript(return value of function) in android please advice.

Thanks

Answer (score 11):

I had the same problem and I have found a solution here: [Problems using Rhino on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3859305/problems-using-rhino-on-android)

By default, rhino will try do optimization by generating JVM bytecode on the fly. Android doesn't run JVM bytecode byt Dalvik bytecode. That is why you have to disable optimization:

```
context.setOptimizationLevel(-1);
```

Best regards

Comment: where's that method? Doesn't appear in `context`

Comment: context is a "org.mozilla.javascript.Context" object. Make sure you use a right type.