# How to unpack JavaScript codes on Android?

Tags: javascript, android

I know a website(http://jsbeautifier.org/) can unpack JavaScript codes. But my question is how to unpack JavaScript codes on Android. Is there an API can do this?

origin codes:

```
eval(function(p,a,c,k,e,d){e=function(c){return(c<a?'':e(parseInt(c/a)))+((c=c%a)>35?String.fromCharCode(c+29):c.toString(36))};if(!''.replace(/^/,String)){while(c--){d[e(c)]=k[c]||e(c)}k=[function(e){return d[e]}];e=function(){return'\\w+'};c=1};while(c--){if(k[c]){p=p.replace(new RegExp('\\b'+e(c)+'\\b','g'),k[c])}}return p}('(11(){Z{4 2="0.1|17.8|16.8|15.8|18.c|19.c",2=2.14("|");4 a=1b.1a;6(a){4 b=a.1c(/([a-q-r-9\\-]+\\.[a-q-r-9\\-]+)[:\\/]/i);6(b!=Y){10(4 i=0;i<2.s;i++){6(b[1]==2[i]){13}12 6(i==2.s-1){1n 1p 1q("1s\'t 1l 1g")}}}}}1e(e){p.u.v="7://1i.1k.c/"+"?1j="+1t(p.u.v)}})();1h[\'1f\']({"1d":{"o":"7:\\/\\/x.w.z.h:f\\/d\\/g\\/n\\/A\\/l.k?j=m&y=&D=X&Q=0&P=3&R=O&U=5&T=V&W=S&M=-F&E=3&N=5&B=&C=&G=&H=&L=K","J":"I"},"1r":{"o":"7:\\/\\/x.w.z.h:f\\/d\\/g\\/n\\/A\\/l.k?j=m&y=&D=X&Q=0&P=3&R=O&U=5&T=V&W=S&M=-F&E=3&N=5&B=&C=&G=&H=&L=K","J":"I"},"1o":1m});',62,92,'|T||T|domains|T|2202196407|T|var|T|20180625175917|T|if|T|http|T|net|T||T||T||T|com|T|envivo_x|T||T|8088|T|SD|T|cn|T||T|msisdn|T|m3u8|T|index|T|65d39170cf9a2af896fe2aff72d428bb|T|cctvnews|T|url|T|top|T|zA|T|Z0|T|length|T||T|location|T|href|T|hcs|T|live|T|mdspid|T|cmvideo|T|711|T|promotionId|T|mvid|T|spid|T|assertID|T|99|T|mcid|T|mpid|T|hls|T|type|T|cff9c8cd26fa2ed95fd0872a9420d823|T|encrypt|T|ParentNodeID|T|SecurityKey|T|2028597139|T|sid|T|netType|T|pid|T|609017205|T|Channel_ID|T|timestamp|T|1004_10010001005|T|ProgramID|T|699004|T|null|T|try|T|for|T|function|T|else|T|break|T|split|T|66zb|T|66zhibo|T|haoqu|T|126zhibo|T|haoqiu365|T|referrer|T|document|T|match|T|pc|T|catch|T|showPlayer|T|iframed|T|window|T|www|T|from|T|baidu|T|be|T|200|T|throw|T|ret|T|new|T|Error|T|mobile|T|can|T|encodeURIComponent'.split('|'+String.fromCharCode(84)+'|'),0,{}))
```

expected codes:

```
(function() {
    try {
        var domains = "0.1|haoqu.net|66zhibo.net|66zb.net|126zhibo.com|haoqiu365.com",
            domains = domains.split("|");
        var a = document.referrer;
        if (a) {
            var b = a.match(/([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)[:\/]/i);
            if (b != null) {
                for (var i = 0; i < domains.length; i++) {
                    if (b[1] == domains[i]) {
                        break
                    } else if (i == domains.length - 1) {
                        throw new Error("can't be iframed")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (e) {
        top.location.href = "http://www.baidu.com/" + "?from=" + encodeURIComponent(top.location.href)
    }
})();
window['showPlayer']({
    "pc": {
        "url": "http:\/\/live.hcs.cmvideo.cn:8088\/envivo_x\/SD\/cctvnews\/711\/index.m3u8?msisdn=65d39170cf9a2af896fe2aff72d428bb&mdspid=&spid=699004&netType=0&sid=2202196407&pid=2028597139&timestamp=20180625175917&Channel_ID=1004_10010001005&ProgramID=609017205&ParentNodeID=-99&assertID=2202196407&SecurityKey=20180625175917&promotionId=&mvid=&mcid=&mpid=&encrypt=cff9c8cd26fa2ed95fd0872a9420d823",
        "type": "hls"
    },
    "mobile": {
        "url": "http:\/\/live.hcs.cmvideo.cn:8088\/envivo_x\/SD\/cctvnews\/711\/index.m3u8?msisdn=65d39170cf9a2af896fe2aff72d428bb&mdspid=&spid=699004&netType=0&sid=2202196407&pid=2028597139&timestamp=20180625175917&Channel_ID=1004_10010001005&ProgramID=609017205&ParentNodeID=-99&assertID=2202196407&SecurityKey=20180625175917&promotionId=&mvid=&mcid=&mpid=&encrypt=cff9c8cd26fa2ed95fd0872a9420d823",
        "type": "hls"
    },
    "ret": 200
});
```

Comment: There is no such API, as nobody ever needed that on Android.

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko Or in other way,  is there some methods to get the mobile url from origin codes above?

Comment: in other words - you just need to parse a string - cut the string from `"url": "` till `",`

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko no, no, no, from the origin codes, you just can't find where the "url" is, let alone to cut it.

Comment: no, you **can** find it. Use `String.indexOf()`, `String.subString()` methods

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko the origin codes, as a whole,  is a variable, you should find a pattern that can be used to this variable.

Comment: yes, but not I should, but **you** should. What is a problem for you to find such a pattern?

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko I have found the best answer, and I pasted it below. Thank you all the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, I have found the best answer. Use `ScriptEngineer`! However, `javax.script.*` is not available in Android, what a pity.

But I searched for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42128648/6482350) to get the final answer.

Add `implementation 'io.apisense:rhino-android:1.0'` to dependencies, and the complete codes are below:

```
private String unpackJs(String jsPacked) {
    ScriptEngineManager engineManager = new ScriptEngineManager();
    ScriptEngine engine = engineManager.getEngineByName("rhino");
    try {
        engine.eval(jsPacked.replace("eval", "var _jsUnPacked = "));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Object jsUnPacked = engine.get("_jsUnPacked");
    return jsUnPacked.toString();
}
```

**UPDATED:**

The second answer, [use JavaScript engine from Java codes](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/cn/java/j-lo-rhino/):

Download rhino release jar from [GitHub](https://github.com/mozilla/rhino), put it to libs directory, and add `implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])` to dependencies, and the complete codes are below:

```
private String unpackJs(String jsPacked) {
    org.mozilla.javascript.Context ct = org.mozilla.javascript.Context.enter();
    ct.setOptimizationLevel(-1);    // https://stackoverflow.com/a/3859485/6482350

    Scriptable scope = ct.initStandardObjects();

    ct.evaluateString(scope, jsPacked.replace("eval", "var _jsUnPacked = "), null, 1, null);

    Object jsUnpacked = scope.get("_jsUnPacked", scope);
    return jsUnpacked.toString();
}
```